# difference on times procedure execution in mysql console

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, time, console

When I execute a mysql procedure on the console, this always show two times but I don't know what time each thing refers to.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure must do a SELECT followed by some non-SELECT.

Here's a demo:

```
mysql> delimiter ;;
mysql> create procedure p() begin select 123; do 123+456; end;;
mysql> delimiter ;

mysql> call p;
+-----+
| 123 |
+-----+
| 123 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

The two times reported are for the two SQL statements run in the procedure.

- The first statement returned a row.
- The second statement did not return a row, but still had to execute, therefore it reported its time.

Statements that have a result set include SELECT and SHOW.

All other statements have no result set, but may *affect* rows. Like if an UPDATE changes rows, it will report it affected some number of rows, which are the rows it changed.

The quick example I showed in my demo only uses the `DO` statement, which evaluates an expression but doesn't change any data or return any data.